# fatal error rpc/rpc.h while using "make" command for mySQL installation

Tags: mysql, linux, makefile, centos, rpc

I am trying to install mySQL on CentOS with source code and when I use "make" command then I get error on 60%

```
/root/mysql-5.7.20/rapid/plugin/group_replication/libmysqlgcs/scr/bindings/xcom/xcom/pax_msg.c:16:10: fatal error: error/rpc.h: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: There's a line in  `pax_msg.c` , line 16, saying : `#include <rpc/rpc.h>` . ...... Now the CentOS 8 `glibc-devel` has omitted the ancient Sun / Oracle rpc headers. A fix https://superuser.com/questions/1533171/rpc-header-not-found-despite-being-installed/1534271#1534271